# how to use z-index with relative positioning?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a problem with `z-index` and my code. I want to have a popup on every row, positioned relative to that row. So I created this code:

```css
   .level1
    {
        position:relative;
        z-index:2;
    }
    .level2
    {
        position:relative;   
        z-index:3;
    }
    .popup
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:10px;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:yellow;
        z-index:4;
    }
```

```html
<div class="level1">
        <div class="level2">
            <input type="text" value="test1" />
            <div class="popup">test1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="level2">
            <input type="text" value="test2" />
            <div class="popup">test2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing? `.level1` does not exapand in height to fit `.popup`? `.popup` appears behind something?

Comment: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex

Answer (score 80):

When you set `position: relative` on an element then you establish a new containing block. All positioning inside that block is with respect to it.

Setting z-index on an element inside that block will only alter its layer with respect to other elements inside the same block.

I'm not aware of any work-arounds.

Answer (score 17):

try adding z-index with negative values to the back divs

Comment: Wow... I wasn't expecting this to do anything, but it totally solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Good trick. Have never thought of using -ve value zindex's :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `z-index` with the `relative` position. You just need to specify `position: relative`. If you really want it to look like it is popping up, I suggest using `box-shadow`

```
.popup {
    position:relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:yellow;
    z-index: 4;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(213,213,213,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(213,213,213,0.6);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(213,213,213,0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(213,213,213,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 0px rgba(213,213,213,0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Z-Index is a rule order which results will be visible ONLY when two or more elements overlap. This means that if you want to have same z-index behaviour as in absolute position you'll need to make them overlap. Position relative don't make them overlap, so for example in this example, to make this two divs to overlap, I have to set the second one's top to -50px.

```
  <div style="background-color: blue; width: 500px; height: 100px; position: relative">
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 50px; height: 50px; position: relative; z-index: 1;  top: 0px"></div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 50px; height: 50px; position: relative; z-index: 0; top: -50px"></div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: This answer is wholly incorrect. `z-index` applies to any positioned element. "overlapping" has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You're right, technically is applied always, but you'll only see results when overlapping.