# Parent behind the element but its child on the element

Tags: html, css, z-index

I want to move `div` behind the parent element, but still elements in the `div` to raise up and to be able to click them. I tried to use `z-index` but it seems or I don't know to use it properly or it doesn't work in a way I need.

So parent div should be behind container, but child `div`s should be on the container.

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "parent">
        <div class = "child"></div>
        <div class = "child"></div>
        <div class = "child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. http://driglou.pusku.com/moreira/ so here is what i try to do, and i need `.labels` to be behind the `.header` and `.label_icon` to be on the header, so you would be able to click this `.label_icon`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough time to recreate the situation or find a working solution - all i could see in the minute i checked your example was the usage of the position-style element.

Maybe you could checkout that article ([how to use z-index with relative positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986071/how-to-use-z-index-with-relative-positioning?answertab=votes#tab-top)) and see if it helps because you are switching positions (relative and absolute) between your parent/child elements.

Hope that this answer helps you any further.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the link all you need to do is set a container then an image for the head, and then headers for the tabs, and finally the link image.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="parent_header">
        <div class="tab1"></div>
        <div class="tab2"><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></div>
        <div class="tab3"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the absolute positioning on class and apply instead to individual ID'

Comment: Can you tell me exactly from which class to take absolute positioning? Because im lost a bit :/

Comment: You've applied absolute positioning (left: 50%) to .label_icon which you have assigned to all 3 img's, so absolute will position them all in the same space, instead position them each with an ID or use margin: 0 auto; on the class if you just want them each centered.