# Z-Index With Position: Relative

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I am trying to transfer a mobile app design into a website. I need to keep some elements in the same place over different resolution screens and window sizes. I am using relative positioning for all my positioning but I can't seem to get the elements to overlap using Z-Index. The other thread did not answer my question because it is not the same situation since I am not using JavaScript. How can I get it to work? [Here is what I am trying to do:](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=87623709099648356076)

And here is my code:

```css
 /* Font */
 @font-face {
   font-family: Museo300-Regular;
   src: url(Museo300-Regular.otf)
 }
 /* Nav */
 html {
   height: 100%
 }
 body {
   background-image: url('images/bg-img.jpg');
   font-family: Museo300-Regular, Museo700-Regular;
   display: flex;
   height: 100%;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
 }
 #wrapper {
   position: relative;
 }
 #wrapper > div {
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 960px;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
 }
 #wrapper > div#home {
   width: 255px;
   height: 254px;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* Safari */
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 #wrapper > div#contact {
   width: 255px;
   height: 254px;
   position: relative;
   top: 70%;
   left: 40%;
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* Safari */
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Micah Friesen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <!-- page content -->
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="home">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/homebttn.png" title="Homepage (Here)" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <img src="images/contactbttn.png" title="Contact Me, this also includes Rates" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest using bootstrap to make life easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use z-index with relative positioning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986071/how-to-use-z-index-with-relative-positioning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to put elements in well defined position in the screen.
Thus, it not good practice to use relative position because these element will be depending in each other. If, for instance, you want move one element, it's probably will move also the others.

Better option is to use absolute or fixed position for the elements.
You can found more details here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Also, in my example I've used 'vh' units (vector height) witch scaling the elements to fit the screen size. Pay attention, it's new units so they may not supported in very old browsers.

Simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="aboutMe"></div>
    <div id="contactMe"></div>
    <div id="news"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #aboutMe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20vh;
        width: 40vh;
        height: 50vh;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #contactMe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70vh;
        width: 40vh;
        height: 20vh;
        background-color: green;
    }

    #news {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20vh;
        left: 40vh;
        width: 40vh;
        height: 70vh;
        background-color: orange;
    }
```

Result:

[image: Example]

Comment: If I use absolute positioning on both objects they will not move at all. All objects go to where the first object cascading in css is located at. So in this case it would be the #homebttn and will not move.

Comment: Controll the objects' positions by adding top/bottom/left/rigth attributes to the css. See the example above.