# How to implement an white box over an image correct in asp.net

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an booking box with an white background over an image on my front page. So far I have managed to put an box on top with the following code:

**Code:**

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 contentpage">        
    <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="~/images/index.jpg" />

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="bookingbox">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                      
</div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
 .bookingbox {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -580px;
    margin-left: 10px;

 }

 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .bookingbox {
        display: none;
    }
 }
```

The problem now is that when you going from, lets say 1600px to 1200px the white box moves, can't make it to be static inside the image.

All my images are set with the following css the they become responsive:

```
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

What should I change? any ideer?

**Update:**

The box fitting perfectly now.. but now the image is off the aligniment with the rest of the page.

[image]

Left side is good, but right side has become bigger somehow?

Comment: I would start by using percentage position values rather than fixed pixel margin values.

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ddmvyqt), you should use `z-index` to do this.

```css
.bookingbox {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
 }

.frontimage {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .bookingbox {
        display: none;
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 contentpage">        
    <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg" />

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="bookingbox">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                      
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't want to make my front image absolute.. is this the only solution?

Comment: yep, `z-index` you must use only with `position: absolute` of `position: fixed`. As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ddmvyqt/1), `position: relative` don't work

Comment: @Mikkel same question as you have [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986071/how-to-use-z-index-with-relative-positioning)

Comment: Well it works.. but now the image is out of alignment with the rest of the page.. have made an image of how it looks.

Comment: @Mikkel that's impossible, `z-index` works just with `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;`

Comment: Do you know why the image does not align anymore? like before? you can see that right side is not aligned with the rest of the page.

Comment: yes, if you have `position: absolute;` you can move this object, just with top/bottom/right/left. Margins and padding will not work