# CSS z-index Not Functioning (relative positioning used, top and left used)

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I have the following code to make 'b' (div) go above 'More text' (Text node):

JavaScript, HTML and Output:

```js
function InsertDetails() {

  document.getElementById("UI-Slide-Content").focus();
  var HTMLToInsert = "div";

  var sel, range, html;
  var text = HTMLToInsert;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();

      range.insertNode(document.createTextNode("More text"));

      var b = document.createElement("div");
      b.style.zIndex = "2";
      b.style.position = "relative";
      b.style.backgroundColor = "lightGray";
      b.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Details"));
      b.style.padding = "5px";
      range.insertNode(b);

      var a = document.createElement(text);

      a.setAttribute("onclick", "DetailsSwitch(this);");

      a.style.backgroundColor = "buttonFace";
      a.innerHTML = "&#9660;&nbsp;Summary";
      a.style.padding = "5px";
      range.insertNode(a);
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    //MessageBox("Feature Not Supported", "This feature does not work in Internet Explorer.");
  }

}

function DetailsSwitch(a) {
  var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  var c = 0;
  var d = a;
  var e = null;

  while (c < allDivs.length) {
    if (allDivs[c] == d) {
      e = allDivs[c + 1];
    }
    c++;
  }

  if (e.style.display == "block") {
    e.style.display = "none";
    d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML.replace("▼&nbsp;", "▶&nbsp;");
  } else {
    e.style.display = "block";
    d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML.replace("▶&nbsp;", "▼&nbsp;");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="UI-Slide-Content" contenteditable style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; height: 100%;">UI-Slide-Content</div>
<button onclick="InsertDetails();">Insert Details Pane</button>
```

Try clicking on the 'Insert Details Pane' button, and this would insert a details pane (not using native HTML `<details/>` tag) that the user can edit. I desire to make the details show up below the 'Summary' box (on the y-axis) and above the 'More text' text node (on the z-axis).

But then, it does not work. 'More text' gets shifted down when the pane is open. I desire to have 'More text' not move by making the details pane's details box go above the 'More text' using `z-index`. It does not work.

I have read many questions similar to this, and have found out that

> using 'top' and 'left'attributes can help ([CSS z-index not working with relative positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611927/css-z-index-not-working-with-relative-positioning))
>
> using relative positioning may also help (another question)

But then, I tried these two, but without success.

May someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your “More text” moves down on the **Y** axis – so naturally **z**-index does nothing in that regard. If you want it to stay in place, then you need to position your “Details” _absolutely_, because that will take it out of the flow, so that it does not influence the position of following elements any more.

Comment: Where is your upper z-index defined? I see a defaults value of '2' for what I assume is the low value. The upper value should be 10 levels higher.

Comment: @CBroe. This code has several issues to be addressed. I suggest it be re-coded from scratch. The DOM will not work properly with this code, and there is the issue of z-index collision.

Comment: @Sparky256: Yeah, but my intention wasn’t to comment on the code quality, but just to explain to the OP where they are misunderstanding what z-index actually does (and what not.)

Comment: Understood @CBroe. I was merely suggesting that it will take more than a z-index fix to make this code work. The OP needs to understand the DOM as well.

Comment: It would help to make your code cleaner and easier to read if you were to take out all non-dynamic css: e.g. `b.style.padding = "5px";` and place into a stylesheet file or embedded stylesheet like in **[this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/y3ahmtk8/)**. Then at least we have a fighting chance at clearing things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though [some websites claim](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) this...

> z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed)

... the only W3 code example uses `position:absolute`. So we can't use `position:relative` to get elements to stack on top of each other.

See example 16 in the CSS 3 WG Spec from October 2015: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#propdef-z-index

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/pd194qub/) which illustrates how the light gray box can be positioned over the darker gray button, using `position:absolute;`

Comment: The CSS3 book declares that only position:fixed; (like tool- bars), or position:absolute; (follows the page as it scrolls) allows a div to be moved or hidden or have adjustable z-index. A collision can take place if objects occupy the same space and z-index. After writing 10's of thousands of lines of css, I know this too well.

Comment: Of course z-index works on elements with `position:relative` – it’s explicitly specified so. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#propdef-z-index: _“Applies to: positioned elements”_, https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#box-offsets-trbl: _“An element is said to be positioned if its position property has a value other than static.”_

Comment: _“... the only W3 code example uses position:absolute”_ – an _example_ does not have to cover all possibilities; that’s like saying the aliens come to earth, abduct one male human being – and then from that sample/example deduce, that _all_ of earth’s population was male.

Comment: I'd love to see Chrome work that way, but so far it doesn't. Without examples of how it should work for the Chrome developers to read & think about, they probably didn't realize that they needed to build Chrome to use z-index with `position: relative;`, `position: fixed;`, etc.... So for now we're stuck using `position: absolute;` until they correct Chrome in some future update.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Using z-index on relative positioned elements works perfectly fine in Chrome – proof: https://jsfiddle.net/a3wj7vg2/ And that has worked from the very beginning – no need to wait for a “better future” …

Comment: @CBroe We were trying to fiddle with the JS example above, not use a pure CSS solution. I don't know why it wasn't working with the pure vanilla JS example & Chrome today. Personally, I'd rewrite the code to use CSS & jQuery, but in the spirit of trying to help out user5719584, I was attempting to modify the code using native JS. I have no idea why native JS didn't work as well as pure CSS.

Comment: Then I don’t understand how you come from having a specific (messed-up) example script not working as intended, to the conclusion that z-index was generally broken in Chrome and that the Chrome devs didn’t do their homework …

Comment: Your code example is the first one that I've seen of using z-index with `position: relative;` I usually use it with `position: absolute;` as it tends to work out better for me. It is a good code example & I've learned something new today! Thanks!

Comment: I use Chrome and have created pages where the 'relative position' scrollable page is z-index 1 (typical). Adjusting z-index at the relative level needs a change of+/- 100 at least to work-and is not as dependeble as using abosulte positioning. Navigation and pop-up text often use 'abosulte' so they stay above the page but follow it along. 'Abosulte' is referenced to the div it was created in, including children. 'Fixed' is for tool-bars and are seldom used except for styling control or diagnostics. Every position type has its purpose. I think I have worn this subject out...