# Why using absolute position causes the div to be on top?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Please see this very simple snippet to illustrate my question below:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

#back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12" id="container">
  <div id="back"></div>
  <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

The `h1` tag is *after* the `back` element, in the HTML code.

As I don't change its `position` property, it must be `static`.
And, as far as I know, `static` elements are positioned according to the flow of the page.

So… Why is the absolute-positioned `div` **is shown above** its sibling `h1`?

I am expecting to see it behind the `h1` since it comes first.

Note that I know how to *correct* this behaviour, I'm just asking why!

Snippet with correction:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

#back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

/* Adding the below corrects this behaviour */

h1 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12" id="container">
  <div id="back"></div>
  <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

… And why using `position: relative` on the `h1` corrects this behaviour?

Comment: When you position an element absolutely, you remove it from the flow of the DOM. There's a helpful [explanation here](https://maymay.net/blog/2004/11/20/centering-absolute-positioning-and-document-flow/)

Comment: @Lewis Does it mean that using `position: relative` like in my 2nd snippet also removes the `h1` from the flow?

Comment: No. I'm not 100% sure of the mechanics, but I think when you add `position:relative` to an element, it gains the ability to move along the z-index (try z-indexing an element without a position, it'll do nothing). It is established with a default value of `:auto`. More good info in this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986071/how-to-use-z-index-with-relative-positioning?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (Look at Quentin's answer specifically).

Comment: @Lewis it has nothing to do with z-index, but this is the logical paiting order

Comment: @TemaniAfif The logical painting order when considering positioned elements, yes - which for all intents and purposes, adding `position: relative` to an element gives it z-index: 0, no? (Genuine question)

Comment: @Lewis no, am talking about the logical painting order considering all the elements (as described in my answer) and z-index has nothing to do here ... and it will not be 0 by default but it's `auto` (it may be the same but not exactly)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, 0 for all intents and purposes. I did mean to refer to `:auto` as I mentioned before though. Interesting stuff, nice answer.

Comment: @Lewis read the step 8 closely and you will see the difference between auto and 0 in z-index. 0 will create a stacking context BUT auto will not and there is a big difference here ;)

Comment: @dippas I have to disagree that this is a duplicate. The accepted answer says "position: relative […] is nothing but same as static"… But adding `position: relative` prevents my issue in my 2nd snippet! So it's not the same at all!

Comment: I also totally disagree with the duplicate .. it has nothing to do with this question. it's not about how different positons works but how the painting order works .. reponned the question

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, I feel less stupid. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the painting order works. As described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) you have the following order:

> 4. For all its **in-flow**, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order: If the element is a block, list-item, or other block
>      equivalent:

In this step you will print the background and border of the `h1` element

> 7. Otherwise: first for the element, then for all **its in-flow**, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order:

In this *complex* step you will print the content of the `h1` element

> 8. All **positioned**, opacity or transform descendants, in tree order that fall into the following categories:
>
>    1. All **positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto'**

And in this step you will print the positioned element `#back`; thus it will be on the top of `h1` even if in the DOM it's before.

In other words, we first consider the in-flow elements then the postioned ones. Of course, changing `z-index` and/or other properties will affect the order because more steps can be consider.

---

For example adding a negative `z-index` to `#back` will trigger this rule:

> 3. Stacking contexts formed by positioned descendants with negative z-indices (excluding 0) in z-index order (most negative first) then
>      tree order.

This will make the `#back` to be behind since `h1` is printed later in the step (4) and (7).

---

Adding `position:relative` (or `absolute` or `fixed`) to `h1` will make it a positioned element so like `#back` it will trigger the (8) and in this case the **tree order** will decide.

---

You may also notice that both background and content are printed in 2 different steps and this may also lead to [some *non intuitive* painting behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731110/strange-behavior-of-background-when-elements-are-overlapping).

Comment: By the way, I already came upon your question you linked… It's crazy.

Answer (score -1):

Try following. Add style for `h1` as follows

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

#back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
#container h1 {
  position : relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12" id="container">
  <div id="back"></div>
  <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

`static elements` do not have a `z-index`, however, the others `default to 0` that is why it stays at the bottom most layer of html and the non-static element covers it. If you wish to show them above, set the `position` of static elements to `relative` and give any `positive z-index value`.

Comment: @TakitIsy - Updated answer

Comment: The `z-index` isn't needed, see the 2nd snippet in my question.

Comment: @TakitIsy - If the elements have same z-index, the last one overlaps. However, if you change the order, of `h1` and `div#black` then you will need `z-index`

Answer (score -1):

The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`, and `z-index` properties have no effect for `position: static` which is the default value for elements, in your case which `h1` tag is. When position is set to relative it creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is other than auto.

For more read on stacking context:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: I know about the *no effect for position: static*. Note that I didn't use any of the properties you mentioned on my `h1`.

Comment: Your `h1` element by default is `position: static` where `z-index` does not work. When you use `position: relative` for `h1` a new stacking context is created in which default `z-index` is set.